# PHP XMLReader doesn't give any error on invalid characters

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd, xmlreader

I would like to read uploaded XML files. These files sometimes have invalid characters and I would like to handle these cases gracefully. I tried every error handling method I know of, but it seems like, that it is not possible to catch these errors.

Currently, I use XSD validation with `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```php
/**
 * Helper method to read the XML file and validate its data and structure
 *
 * @param[in] string $xml_file
 *   The xml file
 * @param[out] array $errors
 *   A place to store all the errors, if needed
 * @return array 
 *   The data from the xml file parsed into an array
 */
private function parseXML($xml_file, &$errors) : array {
    $data = array();
    
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    if (!$reader->open($xml_file, "utf-8")) {
        $errors[] = "XMLReader couldn't open file";
        return $img_data;
    }
    
    // Load XSD file for xml validation
    $xsd_file = Storage::disk('local')->path('record.xsd');
    $reader->setSchema($xsd_file);
    
    // XMLReader error handling:
    // https://www.codementor.io/@sirolad/validating-xml-against-xsd-in-php-6f56rwcds
    // do error handling internaly
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    while($reader->read()) {
        if (!$reader->isValid()) {
            $errors[] = "Found invalid XML.";
            $xml_errors = libxml_get_errors();
            foreach ($xml_errors as $xe) {
                $xestr = "Error $xe->code in $xe->file (Line:{$xe->line}):";
                $xestr .= trim($xe->message);
                $errors[] = $xestr;
            }
            libxml_clear_errors();

            $reader->close();
            return $img_data;
        }

        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Entry') {
            // extract the relevant data
        }
    }
    $reader->close();
    return $data;
}
```

And here are the relevant files:
XSD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- definition of attributes -->
<xs:attribute name="Text" type="xs:string"/>

<!-- definition of complex elements -->
<xs:element name="Entry">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute ref="Text" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Logs">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Entry" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Logs>
  <Entry Text="Foo Bar" />
  <Entry Text="Bla: 0x25äX7()&quot;29u9U&quot;)E$/((§/&#x10;$/&amp;(%&quot;%l7M§ä6'+äÄ'*Ä2+ä3+ÄejXÖÜ*d'ö+Ä'*Ä*'üäÜ'*ÄÖ'ÄÖ'ä7öT" />
  <Entry Text="Foo Bar" />
</Logs>
```

My function stops parsing the XML file on the second `Entry` without writing anything to the `$errors` list. The relevant illegal character is `&#x10;`. My dream solution would be to somehow still get this string **with** the illegal character.

For now, I would like to know, why all my XML validation does absolutely nothing in this case and just stops parsing. I can see, that everything after the entry with the illegal character is ignored.
First I thought `$reader->read()` returns false reading this entry. So I checked `libxml_get_errors()` after the `while`-loop, but it is still empty.

Questions:

1. So how do I catch if this problem does even exist in the current XML?
2. How do I get the full content of the text attribute and still parse the rest of the file?

**Edit:**

Interestingly [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=67b9195df68d10a193a684aba2dad2fe90560609-1621938945-0-AfW8OR8CMVYqxR252b9UvG2fBmr8MJpCK4ddZ0JUWcFn61QEwgPHM37Zsf-2Sp8FjSyzoR8JiFN-nQdgbAniJ8Slvsk9lhlekLLHvWWs0rsEFNqghgMH9D9atGj7sMcykUDpznnCOPEf_pVutj7JOR_FHOpaV7u9CLTAfEe-g-afzZe996r_nZwz4iTdjw3ktLNWuwAyJatNVZgUM5NTjD71dMz1fs7ZyL3GtHczKw4NW_c9MZRHd5D1VaQk49U_dibbMelKeMImrMrd1dd5IG7tCFUpWkcamjaAO7kRkKu8diIOsbdCbFloApEux1Iuhk-69UwfTAitHNzFgcLLswr0MQefi9lXOpShSzNS7TATNDTixJYu8hEBBwcNCEny5oswFAZl9izgqbXK-KGfto1TPLb7dqEmVucmEjH9nNslY9SWsbJ8Zk_8glUPXfXAiJHzmOIUDGGJ9_X6lOAdn13YwGGpevNp533EP8aF8AcKS4-DiiJnDwZtxkHtXfjdM4uC95FDmSG6aC5EjutghboSHh_lfhGWv0OMMO7FbhKxY6UPucEQtKLoXAVUZlzKyJwCY1AqYb6YaF1Gn666lc0MwTgIBkK0s96tWaZcAVPPgAdPvy0cAHHT0y_kiMgfAw) says that my example is valid XML, while [https://www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and [xmlvalidation.com](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) are saying it isn't.

Comment: Why not use `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` to validate the xml files first against the xsd schema and then do the reading part

Comment: @Haridarshan Because I don't use `DOMDocument`. I use [`XMLReader`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) if this wasn't clear. I mean I could use `DOMDocument` as well, but this seems a little bit redundant.